# Ms Access Criteria Checkbox with HAVING IIF Statement

Tags: criteria, iif

I can't get the "Less Than" criteria correct for the false part of the IIf statement:  **<=**[Forms]![BuildLocationKey]![Building1].[value].  This is fed with 8 other rows to another query which outputs a list of sequential temporary numbers that are printed out as a location identification. Using the Criteria box as I haven't had any luck this working with VBA, but am open to any suggestions.

[BuildCB] is the Checkbox

SELECT DISTINCT Building.Bu
FROM Building
GROUP BY Building.Bu
HAVING (((Building.Bu)=IIf([BuildCB],[Forms]![BuildLocationKey]![Building1].[value],"<=[Forms]![BuildLocationKey]![Building1].[value]")));

Comment: You are doing this in query builder? The operator (<, >, =, and so forth) cannot be dynamic. Placing it within quote marks defines it as just a set of text characters, not logical operators. I NEVER use dynamic parameterized queries. I build filter criteria in VBA and apply to form or report when opening. Review http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: Filter criteria is applied to dataset. Can't dynamically change the criteria because of a value in each record. Either you want all records where `field = parameter` or you want all records where `field <= parameter`.

Comment: I used VBA Filtering to make it work.  I knew the way I was going wasn't the best way, but I was thinking it was temporary data...  Thank You you for your time and your comments.